# Where can I find a good tutorial on how to make a multi-use database class using php and mysql?

Tags: php, database, security, prepared-statement

I've been trying for hours to make one class file to handle all the database work (statements, security (sql injection prevent), etc) so I won't have to keep writing statements to do an update or an insert every time i need one. Are there tutorials online that will show you how to create a multi-purpose database class but will prepared statements?

He is the class I tried to construct but my brain is killing me. :S

```
    <?php

$d = new database(); // test

class database {

    protected $db_connect;
    protected $statement;

    function database() {
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "") or die("Could not connect to the server.");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();  
        }
        try {
            $this->preparedQuery("INSERT INTO feedback (name, feedback) VALUES (?, ?)", 
                array("this is my name", "this is my feedback w00t feedback"));
        } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();  
        }
    }

    protected function cleanParameter($strLine) {
        $strCleansedLine = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $strLine);
        return $strCleansedLine;
    }

    public function preparedQuery($strQuery, $parameters = NULL, $types = NULL) {
        try {
            $query = $this->db->prepare($strQuery);


            if ($this->startsWith(strtolower($strQuery), "select")) {
                echo "no";
            } else {
                // insert, update, delete here. 
                $params;
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($parameters); $i++) {
                    $parameters[$i] = $this->cleanParameter($parameters[$i]);
                    $params = array($i => $parameters[$i]);
                    $query->bindValue(do($i), $params[$i]); // still won't work
                    //echo $params[$i]."<br />";
                }

                // maybe this could work?
                foreach($params as $key => $value) {
                    //$d = explode("\ ", $value);
                    echo $params[$key]."------------------";
                    //echo $key."<br />".$value." -----------------";
                    $query->bindValue($key, $value);
                }
            }


            //$this->statement->bind_param("ss", $name, $feedback);


            //$query->execute();

            $this->close();
            echo "Done!";
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    protected function startsWith($string1, $string2) {
        return strpos($string1, $string2) === 0;    
    }

    protected function close() {
        try {
            /*if ($this->statement != NULL)
                $this->statement->close();
            if ($this->db != NULL)
                $this->db->close();*/
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: its called a Data Access Layer (or DAL for short)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with that class:

- in php 5.x you should define constructor as  `public function __construct()`
- the class constructor should not do ant computation
- you should not have hard-coded settings for connection (provide them as parameter in constructor)
- this code ignores many useful elements of PDO, like : named parameters, value types, etc.
- there should **not** be any `echo`'s within the class

Anyway, what exactly is the responsibility of your class ?

If you want to abstract the logic that handles data interaction with database, you should try to implement [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) patterns instead.

Comment: Ignore the testing data (echos, hardcoded sql statements, etc). The goal was to have one class to handle all the interactions between the database and the server so I wouldn't have to keep repeating my self with creating statement for database work.

Comment: Then this class of yours should have nothing to do which creating a connection. Instead what you need is a separate class for connection management (if pure PDO is not enough for you) and then class FeedbackMapper  which takes an object ( or several variables ) and knows how to save them and how to retrieve them from database.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess I wasn't thinking straight (3 hours of sleep last night and it's already 1am.) That does sounds logical. I'll probably end up breaking this down and looking into things of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

Good, you're building on top of PDO... but why are you wrapping it?  You can easily simply extend it and add your convenience methods instead.  For example:

```
class MySpecialSauce extends PDO {

    public function prepareAndExecute($sql, $params) { 
        $sh = $this->prepare($sql);
        return $sh->execute($params);
    }

    public function queryListAssoc($sql, $params) {
        $sh = $this->prepareAndExecute($sql, $params);
        return $sh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    // etc...
}
```

You can also create a class that inherits from PDOStatement, and [set the `PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS` attribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) in the extended PDO object to have it returned instead of a plain vanilla PDOStatement.

However, as others have said, if you're trying to simplify the construction of queries, you might be barking up the wrong tree.  Consider a light-weight ORM like [phpDataMapper](http://phpdatamapper.com) or a query builder like [Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html).  (The two can coexist -- Zend_Db_Select builds on top of Zend_Db, which wraps PDO.  phpDataMapper also wraps PDO.  You can set up the PDO object externally and tell both (or one or the other) to use it instead of doing their own thing.  I'm doing this in a project of mine right now.)